# How to deploy NodeJS Server app using AWS EC2 public IP?

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-ec2, aws-cloud9

I'm using NodeJS and Express.js to run my projects.
In local app preview mode, everything works fine. But the ugly, long, and temporary preview link provided on each preview just doesn't cut it for me and I want someone to be able to access my server via:

```
HTTP://<MY-ELASTIC-IP>:8080
```

I followed the guide here:
[AWS Cloud9 App preview guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/app-preview.html#app-preview-share)

and have my Elastic IP allocated and associated to my EC2 instance running our Cloud9 IDE, I set the inbound security rules as follows:

[Inbound rules of my security group for the EC2 instance running our Cloud9 IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nm4U.png)

Then in my NodeJS app I set the listening port to 8080 (as instructed by the guide), and tried all kinds of listening IP addresses (127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0, (MY-ELASTIC-IP), (MY-PRIVATE-IP)) and tried running the app, hoping I can finally access my server through , but none of them worked.

I'm a seasoned roomie server developer and most of my deployments were through Supervisor, Nginx, Certbot , DNS configuration through my domain registration site, and some router port forwarding and boom my servers would be online in less than 10 minutes.

But really ... what is up with AWS. There's just so much stuff they shoved into this new Cloud9 (I miss the old c9...) and I can't get even the basic stuff done.

What am I missing here? Is there some sort of port forwarding I have to configure between my public elastic IP and my private IPs? I visited most of the similar questions posted about this and still couldn't manage to get my public URL to point to the running NodeJS instance inside C9.

Answer (score 3):

I fought with this forever and finally got access by using listening address '0.0.0.0' and constructed the url using the IPv4 Public IP listed in "Manage EC2 Instance": HTTP://:8080

Not ideal because this Public IP changes each time I launch the environment but solved my immediate problem